# Adding one millisecond to current time objectivec

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to add one millisecond in to current time in objective c . I will fetch the timestamp from server and want to show with millisecond repeatedly ( I dont want to  use the system time)   .Any help is appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is the timestamp an NSDate (or convertible into one)? And what do you mean by 'repeatedly' - update and draw onto screen repeatedly?

Comment: Yes Its in NSDate and I also want to  update and draw onto screen repeatedly. I can use a timer for that . But while running timer i want to add one millisecond to current time repeatedly.

Comment: I guess you know you can't update the screen each millisecond and that you have a good reason for adding 1 millisecond...

Comment: The response time on my Apple display is 12 milliseconds.  That's how long it takes to set a pixel colour and then change it back again.  It seems to me that, even if the iPhone was fast enough to for the software to update the video memory every millisecond,  the display would render (pun intended) that a pointless task.

Comment: @JeremyP That doesn't mean that the device actually displayed the changed pixel. If the display refresh rate is 60Hz (which is what I've seen reported), the display only updates every 17ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the timestamp into an NSDate. Than use

```
+ (id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date
```

Should work.

Comment: +1 Only problem here is that if the iOS system time and the server time disagree, times you calculate based on the timestamp will be wrong. You should instead get the current date (`[NSDate date]`) and the server timestamp, determine the difference, and factor that into the times you generate using the method above.

Comment: How does that work? It would think if you create a NSDate with a date from the server that it is immune to the client settings.

Comment: Right, but if you then pass that date into `+dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` on the device, the date you get back will be relative to whatever the current time on the device is. Let's say the device is an hour different from the server. You get the server time, turn it into a date, and right away call `[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:serverDate]`. You should get a date back that's about an hour different from the date the server gave you, even though the whole transaction took a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an object of the `NSTimer` class.
Some sample code:

```
    -(void)startTimer {

        theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/1000.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        //the method updateTimer will be called once every millisecond
    }

    -(void)updateTimer {
        //add one millisecond to the global time variable and display it in a label
    }

    -(void)stopTimer {
        [theTimer invalidate];  //pauses the timer
    }
```

**Edit**

For using a global Time variable, `NSDate` is probably the right class.
You can init the object using a time interval, for eg. 600 seconds before now:

```
NSDate *globalDateTime = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-600];
```

To add 1 millisecond to the time:

```
globalDateTime = [globalDateTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:1.0/1000.0];
```

And to populate your global time variable in a string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter      = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]; // use yyyy-MM-dd if you need to show the year, month or day
NSString *dateTimeString            = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:globalDateTime];
```

The NSTimeInterval class "yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years."

Refer to apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on NSDate for more details:

Comment: iam only missing the part of add one millisecond to the global time variable and display it in a label. Up to this i already figured out .

Comment: No way an NSTimer is accurate to 1 millisecond.

Comment: @ahwulf, apple's documentation says the interval time is taken as 0.1 milliseconds if you specify a param value less than or equal to 0.
1 millisecond is 10 times as much.

Comment: @Sat--VcanShakeTheWorld--

Just edited my answer with more sample code. The rest should be simple now.

Comment: ["Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)